# Azure API Management vs Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-management-api

New to Azure and would like to know what the difference between Azure API Management and Logic Apps is.

Some pros and cons would be nice. Also what the costing for each of these is like.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `Logic Apps` Or `Azure Function` there is nothing on azure called `Logic Functions`.

Comment: Is there anything that I can help with?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you want to know about `Azure API Management` and `Azure Logic Apps`

Well let me help you what that actually are...

**Azure API Management**

Azure API Management allows organizations to publish APIs more securely, reliably, and at scale. Use API Management to drive API consumption among internal teams, partners, and developers while benefiting from business and log analytics available in the admin portal

*`Pros are`*

1. Consistent and modern API gateways for existing back-end services
2. Verifies API keys, JWT tokens, certificates, and other credentials
3. Help you  to publish APIs to external, partner, and internal
   developers to unlock the potential of their data and services
4. High availability Responds to requests to perform operations at
   least 99.9% of the time.
5. Analytics, metrics and many more

> For further details you could have a look on [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts)

**Pricing**

There are different categories of pricing available based on type and uses. See the below screen shot:

[image]

> You even can read more details about [pricing here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/api-management/)

**Logic Apps:**

Azure Logic Apps is a cloud service that helps you schedule, automate, and orchestrate tasks, business processes, and workflows when you need to integrate apps, data, systems, and services across enterprises or organizations. Logic Apps simplifies how you design and build scalable solutions for app integration, data integration, system integration

*`Pros are`*

1. Maximum automation with hassle free service
2. Process and route orders across on-premises systems and cloud
   services
3. Can move uploaded files from an SFTP or FTP server to Azure Storage
4. Help you connect legacy, modern, and cutting-edge systems more
   easily and quickly by providing prebuilt APIs as Microsoft-managed
   connectors

**Pricing**

Usually two categories of pricing you may have `Consumption pricing model` which depends on how much you consume and have to pay as per your consumption.

another one  `Fixed pricing model`.  See the screen shot:

[image]

> You can have a look more details on [official docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/)

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this - its a great eye opener.